# Stata: counting for this period and next period

Tags: count, stata, data-analysis

I have a data set similar to this and want to create a count variable under these conditions. If `mig` is 1 then count how many of `un1` or `un2` or `un3` are 1 and also count how many of `un1` or `un2` or `un3` in the next time period are 1. So 
I want it to be the count of `un*` in this period and the next for each individual.

I use the code

```
egen ... anycount(un1-un3) if mig ==1 & (un1|un2|un3||f.un1|f.un2 |f.un3)
```

but I cannot get a count of future values.

```
Id  t  mig un1 un2 un3 count
1   1   0   0   1   1   
1   2   0   0   0   1   
1   3   1   0   0   1   4
1   4   0   1   1   1   
1   5   0   0   0   0   
2   1   0   0   1   0   
2   2   1   0   0   0   
2   3   0   1   0   0   1
2   4   0   0   0   1   
2   5   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain this more fully: You have panel data and have `tsset Id t` or similarly using `xtset`.

How about

```
 gen count = cond(mig == 1, un1 + un2 + un3 + F.un1 + F.un2 + F.un3, 0)
```

???